# Requesting for Amadeus enterprise api soap request

Tags: amadeus

I am requesting for Amadeus enterprise api soap request sample for generating nonce, password and created and flight search request with header.

Xml files that i can directly open in postman or soap ui

Comment: You might use a tool designed for SOAP for this.  Something like [XMLSpy](https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor) will generate samples and let you submit them from the service wsdl.  It's the pre-Postman postman.  Docs: [Sending a SOAP Request from the WSDL File](https://www.altova.com/manual/XMLSpy/spyenterprise/xswsdlsoap_wstut_sendsoapreq.html)